# Membership validation fails on login. How to determine cause?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure web site that uses forms authentication with an Azure membership via the standard Microsoft tools and database.  When I website administration tool, it sees the database and creates the users correctly.  When I try to login however, I receive an authentication error.

The really strange part is that I have another Azure website that also uses a membership database.  I copied the membership info directly from that sites web.config file into my broken site.  When I go to administer the website, again, it sees the users correctly but when I attempt to login, I get receive an authentication error.  To be clear, I can login properly from the working site but when I move the config info over to my new site, the same credentials fail.

How can I determine what is causing the problem?  Below is code from web.config:

```
<add name="StrataluxAuthorize" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=StrataluxAuthorize;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/" timeout="600" />
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="StrataluxAuthorize" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="StrataluxAuthorize" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess based on the info given. Be sure that the "ApplicationName" property of the membership profider matches for both sites that will use the same Membership database. It doesn't appear that you have explicitly defined one so I believe by default it will use the Web Project Name. So if there is a mismatch (presumably there would be) between the 2 website names then the membership db will try to create a new application id in the database.

Sample Config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="StrataluxAuthorize" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"  enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Just a bit more clarification:

If you want the users which originaly appeared in web app "A" to be available in web app "B" then the application name in the configuration of web app "B" should be "A". Otherwise the membership provider will view it as a new application and it will get its own id and unique set of users.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't solve it but it has helped me gather some additional information.  If you look to the far right of my original post, you'll see that the applicationName is set to "/".  I looked in the old database and the new database and they both use this.  I also checked the applicationID across the databases and it was correct.  What I did discover though is that I can create a new user through the admin tool and that works fine.  But when I attempt to login with a bad password, it does not increment FailedPasswordAttemps, as if it's pointing to something else.  But what?

Comment: not to "beat a dead horse" (pardon my cliche) but just to confirm... If you run SELECT * FROM aspnet_Applications how many Id's are there? (Assuming only 1)